# Can't debug Golang with breakpoints in VSCode

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I debug Golang application with breakpoints in VS Code.
Debugger complains that can't find file, which exists.

Does anyone of you know how to enable breakpoints for Go application in VS Code?

**Debugger logs:**

```
Debuggee is not running. Setting breakpoints without halting.
All cleared
Creating on: /home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go:63
Creating on: /home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go:84
All cleared
All set:[]
SetBreakPointsResponse
2021-10-21T12:52:17+02:00 debug layer=rpc <- RPCServer.CreateBreakpoint(rpc2.CreateBreakpointIn{"Breakpoint":{"id":0,"name":"","addr":0,"addrs":null,"file":"/home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go","line":63,"Cond":"","HitCond":"","continue":false,"traceReturn":false,"goroutine":false,"stacktrace":0,"LoadArgs":{"FollowPointers":true,"MaxVariableRecurse":1,"MaxStringLen":64,"MaxArrayValues":64,"MaxStructFields":-1},"LoadLocals":{"FollowPointers":true,"MaxVariableRecurse":1,"MaxStringLen":64,"MaxArrayValues":64,"MaxStructFields":-1},"WatchExpr":"","WatchType":0,"hitCount":null,"totalHitCount":0,"disabled":false}})
2021-10-21T12:52:17+02:00 debug layer=rpc -> *rpc2.CreateBreakpointOut{"Breakpoint":{"id":0,"name":"","addr":0,"addrs":null,"file":"","line":0,"Cond":"","HitCond":"","continue":false,"traceReturn":false,"goroutine":false,"stacktrace":0,"LoadArgs":null,"LoadLocals":null,"WatchExpr":"","WatchType":0,"hitCount":null,"totalHitCount":0,"disabled":false}} error: "could not find file /home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go"
2021-10-21T12:52:17+02:00 debug layer=rpc <- RPCServer.CreateBreakpoint(rpc2.CreateBreakpointIn{"Breakpoint":{"id":0,"name":"","addr":0,"addrs":null,"file":"/home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go","line":84,"Cond":"","HitCond":"","continue":false,"traceReturn":false,"goroutine":false,"stacktrace":0,"LoadArgs":{"FollowPointers":true,"MaxVariableRecurse":1,"MaxStringLen":64,"MaxArrayValues":64,"MaxStructFields":-1},"LoadLocals":{"FollowPointers":true,"MaxVariableRecurse":1,"MaxStringLen":64,"MaxArrayValues":64,"MaxStructFields":-1},"WatchExpr":"","WatchType":0,"hitCount":null,"totalHitCount":0,"disabled":false}})
2021-10-21T12:52:17+02:00 debug layer=rpc -> *rpc2.CreateBreakpointOut{"Breakpoint":{"id":0,"name":"","addr":0,"addrs":null,"file":"","line":0,"Cond":"","HitCond":"","continue":false,"traceReturn":false,"goroutine":false,"stacktrace":0,"LoadArgs":null,"LoadLocals":null,"WatchExpr":"","WatchType":0,"hitCount":null,"totalHitCount":0,"disabled":false}} error: "could not find file /home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go"
2
Error on CreateBreakpoint: could not find file /home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go
```

File exists:

```
gbajson@misio:~$ ls -l /home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go
-rw-r--r-- 1 gbajson gbajson 2961 Oct 21 12:22 /home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go
```

I already checked that it's not a problem with file permissions.
I also followed up the procedure for the lagacy version of dlv:
https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging-legacy.md#selecting-legacy-debug-adapter

**Debugger configuration**

- `workspace.code-workspace`

  ```
   "launch": {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {

           "name": "Debug Go",
           "type": "go",
           "request": "launch",
           "mode": "auto",
           "program": "${fileDirname}",
           "debugAdapter": "legacy",
           "env": {},
           "args": [],
           "showLog": true,
           "logOutput": "rpc",
           "trace": "log"
       },
  ```
- `settings.json`

```
{
    "go.delveConfig": {
        "debugAdapter": "legacy",
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. VS Code doesn't handle symbolic links well.
When I set up a project in VS Code in real path debugger started to work properly.

```
gbajson@misio:~$ realpath /home/gbajson/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go
/storage/amoje/Sync/clickr/clickr-node-api/clickr-node-api.go
```

This problem is also described in: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1677

Comment: The problem still remains and also occurs when debugging tests (same problem here, code was under a symlink). Just make sure you open the project from its actual location and everything works.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to share my solution here.
After reading a few [github issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2807) vs-code-go, seems like the issue was a result of `remotePath` or `substitutePath`. After a few attempts, setting `remotePath` to `""` finally did the trick.

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Connect to server",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 40000,
            "host": "<host>",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow-on from the answer by gbajson.

Symbolic links were the problem for me. Using this configuration in launch.json resolved the issue, while allowing me to keep my symlinks:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/server/main.go",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "substitutePath": [
                {
                    "from": "/home/me/go-workspaces",
                    "to": "/data/projects/workspaces"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Specifically, it is the "substitutePath" part.

My workspace directory was actually symlinked from "/home/me/go-workspaces" to the real directory "/data/projects/workspaces".

See: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#debugging-symlink-directories

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sudo ps aux | fgrep {your process name}" to check your process.If it start more than 1 process, maybe you should change your process start mode without daemon process.